# Is there a text editor, editor plugin or NLP algorithm that can deconcatenate a string of words with no space in between

Tags: database, nlp, text-editor

The project I'm working on uses thousands of database tables. In order to understand what the table does, I use the "DESC" command to print out all fields.
But the field names are all a string of words with no space in between, e.g. CREDITORNAME, PRICESOURCE, not very readable.

Is there an editor, an editor plugin or even an NLP algorithm that can deconcatenate a string of concatenated words?

Comment: `sed `s/,/, /g'`

Comment: Not as trivial as you might think (e.g. how to choose between CREDITOR NAME or CREDIT OR NAME?). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20695994/2198727) is a post that might be of use.

Comment: try https://github.com/grantjenks/python-wordsegment